# How to pass an argument to a getElementById method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, getelementbyid

working on a way of displaying information, 8 panels (when each is clicked it expands content below) - however I am trying to add styling so that when one panel is clicked (active) - the background color updates to green and is removed when a new element is clicked. I can't seem to pass the `tabName` parameter to `getElementById` so for now the parameter is hardcoded as `banking-tab` (which does update to green when clicked). Does anyone have any advice for the best possible solution and a potential approach to explore for the remove function?

```js
function onExpandFuncs(tabName) {
  openTab(tabName);
  styleTab(tabName);
}

function openTab(tabName) {
  var i, x;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('containerTab');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
}

function styleTab(tabName) {
  document.getElementById('banking-tab').classList.add('active-column');
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
.active-column {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.containerTab {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Closable button inside the container tab */
.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <h2>Expanding Grid</h2>
      <p>Click on the boxes below:</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div id="banking-tab" class="column" onclick="onExpandFuncs('b1');">
        <img src="./Icons/Banking.svg" />
        <p>Banking</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="regtech-tab" class="column" onclick="onExpandFuncs('b2');">
        <img src="./Icons/Regtech.svg" />
        <p>RegTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="insurtech-tab" class="column" onclick="onExpandFuncs('b3');">
        <img src="./Icons/InsurTech.svg" />
        <p>InsurTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="lending-tab" class="column" onclick="onExpandFuncs('b4');">
        <img src="./Icons/Lending.svg" />
        <p>Lending</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Full-width columns: (hidden by default) -->
    <div id="b1" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h3>Banking</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b2"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>RegTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b3"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>InsurTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b4"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Lending</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b5');">
        <img src="./Icons/Accounting.svg" />
        <p>Accounting</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b6');">
        <img src="./Icons/Payments.svg" />
        <p>Payments</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b7');">
        <img src="./Icons/Quote.svg" />
        <p>Quote Aggregators</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b8');">
        <img src="./Icons/WealthTech.svg" />
        <p>WealthTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b5"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Accounting</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b6"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Payments</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b7"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Quote</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b8"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>WealthTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: does `document.getElementById(tabName)` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is loop over all the tab elements and set up a `click` handler on the each that will set the background color of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), which will represent the element that is handling the event. No need to know or use an `id` (which should be avoided when possible as their use creates brittle code).

Also [don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474).

I've removed all the `onclick` attributes that aren't relevant to this question to avoid errors from their callbacks not being included in the code here.

```js
// Get all the tabs into a collection
// (don't use .getElementsByClassName()!)
let tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".column");

// Loop over all the tabs
tabs.forEach(function(tab){
  // Set up a click event handler on each of the tabs
  tab.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    // Loop over all the tabs and remove the active class
    tabs.forEach(function(tab){
      tab.classList.remove("active-column");
    });
  
    // Set the background of the clicked tab
    this.classList.add("active-column");
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
.active-column {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.containerTab {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Closable button inside the container tab */
.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <h2>Expanding Grid</h2>
      <p>Click on the boxes below:</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div id="banking-tab" class="column">
        <img src="./Icons/Banking.svg" />
        <p>Banking</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="regtech-tab" class="column">
        <img src="./Icons/Regtech.svg" />
        <p>RegTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="./Icons/InsurTech.svg" />
        <p>InsurTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="./Icons/Lending.svg" />
        <p>Lending</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Full-width columns: (hidden by default) -->
    <div id="b1" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h3>Banking</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b2"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>RegTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b3"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>InsurTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b4"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Lending</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" >
        <img src="./Icons/Accounting.svg" />
        <p>Accounting</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" >
        <img src="./Icons/Payments.svg" />
        <p>Payments</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" >
        <img src="./Icons/Quote.svg" />
        <p>Quote Aggregators</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" >
        <img src="./Icons/WealthTech.svg" />
        <p>WealthTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b5"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Accounting</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b6"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Payments</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b7"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Quote</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div
      id="b8"
      class="containerTab"
      style="display: none; background: lightgrey"
    >
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>WealthTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Scott - that works really nicely for adding/ removing the `active-column` class, one thing I notice though is that it seems to have impacted only the top row of expanding content? really appreciate the detailed answer!

Comment: @SimonCunningham It works on both rows of content for me. I just updated my answer to remove other callbacks that weren't included in your code and were throwing errors. Also, I would STRONGLY encourage you to remove all your inline `onclick` event attributes and set up all your event handling in JavaScript as I have done. This will really clean up your HTML and remove redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to work with two different elements.
Hence, you need to pass two different id's in click function. Something like below

```js
function onExpandFuncs(tabName, clickedTab) {
  openTab(tabName);
  genericStyleTab(clickedTab);
}

function genericStyleTab(clickedTab) {
  document.getElementById(clickedTab).classList.add('active-column');
}
```

```html
      <div id="banking-tab" class="column" onclick="onExpandFuncs('b1', 'banking-tab');">
```